# Why is my website not loading and instead getting this error - "Smarty: unable to write file"?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, prestashop, smarty

The error message in full is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: unable to write file /var/www/html/cache/smarty/compile/9d/fc/13/wrt5df05326c094e8_21248361 <-- thrown in /var/www/html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 46
```

I've cleared the "/var/www/html/cache/smarty/compile/" directory, and the "/var/www/html/cache/smarty/cache" directory only has a single "index.php" file (people have suggested clearing this directory too).

I've set permissions to 777 for both these directories (even recursively), and for the smarty_internal_write_file.php also.

I've checked and there is sufficient space on the drive. Also have cleared chrome cache / tried different browsers.

The last time I attempted to access this site was 2-3 months ago and there was no issues. Our website is hosted on an ubuntu EC2 instance on AWS.

I've read an answer somewhere suggesting to contact server host administrators if the above methods didn't work, but I'm not sure how they would be able to help in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

does you script also create the necessary folders? do they exist?

if you just have **/var/www/html/cache/smarty/compile/** and you ask the script to write to **/var/www/html/cache/smarty/compile/9d/fc/13/** the file called **wrt5df05326c094e8_21248361**, then it also needs to first create **/9d** then **/fc** and **/13**.

Not even the option **w+** in *fopen* will create recursively 3 directories.

chmod(777) is a security risk, you should chown the files to the webuser.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a permission issue. Usually directories have: 755 and files: 644.
For time being, disable your cache from admin. And then try to load website.

Comment: How can I disable cache from admin?

Comment: Oh you mean disable cache from within admin site? Issue is I can't load admin site either

Comment: I get the same error when I try to load the admin page, if that's what you mean.